# Files names changed (with strange characters) after being uploaded to cpanel

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

So, after opening a thread here and spending hours, I finally managed to identify my issue.

Long story short, many pictures were not shown on the site after uploading it on namecheap hosting (it was created on the localhost).

I found that since our images had previously different characters (é for example), once uploaded to the store it became (?), thus, no images were shown.

After talking to namecheap support for more than 10 times, they concluded that they can't do anything.

Now, we have more than 5000 pictures on the site so no way to edit one by one as that will take days. I4m not even sure if there is a solution to this. please help

Comment: you see a "?" because you look with a wrong charset. the first step is to try differents charsets to find wich one is the good.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. How can I do that?

Comment: this is how the images titles are shown on cpanel https://i.imgur.com/wqfuqHQ.png

Comment: if you want to convert the filenames programmatically, I recommend that you search the charset in PHP with this function e.g.  https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: Do you have access to ssh terminal over there? Chances are cpanel and server might not be recognizing those characters but there is a possibility that you still can update those filenames.

Comment: I'm not sure I have access, I'm not really a techy person. Can you please let me know how I can update the files names? Thank you.

Comment: Also I do have the site files on localhost (xampp) and everything is working correctly. IS there a way to bulk edit all the images from the localhost then upload another copy to the host? Thank you.